# How to send data to phonegap/cordova app from plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-activity, phonegap-plugins

I have wrote a plugin to open an Android native activity page from phonegap and its working fine. In the native activity page, I have a button. I would like to call a JavaScript function in my phonegap when that button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to [embed a WebView in your Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) and place your button inside an HTML loaded into it. WebView being a mini browser can handle your javascript function. Javascript can call native code through interface but native code cannot call javascript, at least not through WebView.

Answer (score 0):

onClick of button, you need to make a success cordovaCallback with name of the function you want to call.Then,at the javascript side, you need to get that function name in success block and run your function with eval.

Second way is you can create an custom event at javascript side. then send event name with cordovaCallback and fire event at javascript success block.

Answer (score 0):

[Official documentation provides the example](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html) of sending data from native code to javascript.

To send data you need to call the **success** function of the CallbackContext object.

```
callbackContext.success("Native button pressed");
```

You receive and process that data within the success callback in javascript. 
Success callback is provided by you as the first parameter when you call **cordova.exec** method to run your plugin.

Different kinds of data can be sent.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
  Android : this.appView.loadUrl("javascript:yourmethodname()");
  iOS     : [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"javascript:yourmethodname()"];
```